# routing to service on docker swarm

Tags: docker, routes, docker-swarm, docker-container

I have a container that takes a long time to start. When Docker goes into service run state on the swarm, router directs to service, but the browser shows an error because the container is not listening on the port yet. How can I check if the container has started listening on the port? I want to direct after the container starts listening at the port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which kind of reverse proxy you are using for routing, but if you are using Traefik (which is very common with Docker Swarm), you could use error pages: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/errorpages/

Traefik returns a `404` error if your service is not ready yet. So basically if the user tries to connect to this service and gets a 404 error, you can reroute him to another page, until the service is ready.